# Wordpress | Design an entire category (Not category page)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating my first wordpress theme, and I've looked around on google, and the wordpress codex for an answer to my question, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for, or couldn't get it working.

What I'm trying to do, or trying to figure out, is how I can make it so a certain category has a certain design.

So if I wanted to make an index.php for any music videos in "www.domain.com/music/trash/drake-song.mp4.html"
the trash category, it'd have its own design, but songs in
"www.domain.com/music/good-music/coldplay-viva-la-vida.mp4.html"
the good-music category, I want it to look pretty much completely different. I've tried using something similar inside my header.php to this;

```
<?php 
    if( is_tag( 'good-music' ) ):
        $my_classes = array( 'good-class', 'good-class-two' ); 
    else:
        $my_classes = array( 'not-good-class' );
    endif;_

?>
```

but it seemed to simply change the category page.
"www.domain.com/categories/good-music"

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? I know basic html/css/php/javascript, new to creating a WordPress theme, and can't seem to get this working..

Also:
Using XAMPP to host locally, using Friendly URL's, properly configured

Comment: Are you looking to just create a single index.php as a catchall and then update the markup based upon category? Or are you trying to create different page templates for each of the categories?

Comment: I'm trying to design based upon category, as my example I want "good-music" category to have a certain design I can change in a .php, and trash category to have a different design I can create in a different .php file.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a solution for that.

Comment: did you wind up resolving this? If not, can you try the updated code I put in my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate category-specific markup for a single post layout, you can put code like the below in your `single.php` file after the call of `get_header()`.

Please note that this checks for your category based upon category slug. So if your category slug (the url version of your category) does not match the first arguments in the in_array() function call below, then you should change the argument to match the slug for your category.

```
<?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>

        <?php
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $catSlugs = array();
            foreach ($categories as $category){
                $catSlugs[] = $category->slug;
            }
            if (in_array('good-music',$catSlugs)){
                $post_cat = 'good-music';
            } else {
                $post_cat = 'not-good-music';
            }
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', $post_cat );
        ?>

        <?php
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>
```

It is important that this code only appear where there is a query to loop against.

Specifically, the file `single.php` in your theme should be the default file for displaying a single post, regardless of category. When you navigate to the url of a single post, this layout should be triggered.

As part of that triggering, a wordpress query of just that post is returned to be looped through.

Then, the code from `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` until `endwhile;` will run one time, because there is a single post to be processed.

If there were more than one post, such as on a category page or on your default post listing page, then the code inside of that `while` loop would run as many times as there are posts in the query for that layout.

If you were to place the code in the header, it won't work because the header is prepared independently of the loop that runs on this page.

You could run a custom WP_query() in the header, but that is rarely a good way to handle site content.

In this situation it would not be appropriate, because you are customizing content of existing posts, and only differentiating based upon category.

So, just use the standard layouts files with custom layout parts.

I stripped out the divs in the loop below, because you may or may not be using bootstrap.

---

After this code is placed on your page, you would create files called `content-good-music.php` and `content-not-good-music.php` in `YOUR_THEME_DIR/template-parts/post/` directory. The key is that you would add whatever your category slug is to the end of your

These files will contain the unique markup for these kinds of posts. You can also use a similar logic in your post listing loop to give the listed posts for each category their own unique php files.

Here's some `get_template_part()` documentation.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: Tried it, didn't seem to work, I just made an entire comment on how I have common sense, and did change the names to my category names, but apparently I have no common sense, because I accidentally hit F5 before hitting add comment...
I did however, check it, made the MyThemeFolder > template-parts > posts, folder.

Comment: No, it didn't seem to effect it I placed it inside my header, since the header is on every single page.
`
        <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php
            $categories = get_the_category();
            if (in_array('category1',$categories)){
                $post_cat = 'category1';
            } else {
                $post_cat = 'category2';
            }
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', $post_cat );
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
`

Comment: Was I suppose to load anything inside the functions such as
add_theme_support('post-formats');
as well as a certain type?

Comment: Post formats is a different thing.

You can't put the code you had in your comment in the header, unless you set up a custom wp_query, which I don't think you should do in your header.

That's why I suggested you put the code in your `single.php` file, the default file for displaying a single post. The important part of my solution that you might have missed is that you have to run this code "inside a loop."

I will fix my solution to explain better.

Comment: @IndieGuts, I'm sorry for posting bad code previously. I think that if you take the updated code block I placed above into your single.php, you should be able to see the difference (as long as there is content in your template-parts files).

Comment: Sorry about the late response, I actually completed the project using a different strategy, however your answer will be useful to anyone else that wants to do what I was wanting to do.